# Installing jQuery - What Have I Missed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to coding from scratch and use Aptana Studios. I only learned to code through the site Codeacademy so although I can code I am unfamiliar with working with programs like Aptana, linking documents and terminology. So, I apologize in advance for the length of this question. In short, I want **a *full explanation* as to how jQuery can be 'installed'**. I am unsure as to whether 'installed' is the right choice of word in this case so I have provided a more detailed account of my problem below.

---

Everything was going great when I coded the HTML and CSS of a webpage task I had set myself - it was when I needed to use jQuery that I ran into problems. The code I wanted to use was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').hide();
});
```

^^ (just including in case I've made a silly mistake somewhere) ^^

I assume there is something wrong with how I linked my Javascript file to my HTML, or I have failed to properly 'install' jQuery. This is what I did to gain access to jQuery:

I copied the code from the jQuery site into a .js document and saved it in the same folder in which all my HTML and CSS documents are saved. I then linked it to the HTML like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
```

I was completely unable to find any kind of tutorial explaining how this was done in detail. Even the jQuery site's explanation seemed vague to me.

After this I linked my own code to my HTML using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="barns.js"></script>
```

I wasn't amazingly surprised when it didn't work out so I proceeded to go on a hunt for answers but I came back with nothing. This is probably more to do with how I've been taught to code rather than a lack of explanation - my small knowledge of coding vocabulary is evident even in this question - but believe me, the last thing I wanted to do was to ask myself so I really wouldn't be doing this unless I really had run out of options.

Comment: Have you checked for  errors in your browser console?

Comment: Do you have a file named exactly `jquery.js` on the same directory where your html file is located?

Comment: please post your whole code, since it seems everything you wrote down seems fine and should work.

Comment: @user2735777 if you open chrome and access the file, press Ctrl+Shift+J and tell us what you got there.

Comment: @agam360 an error: 'Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined'

Comment: @MarlonBernardes Yes. :)

Comment: @silverarrow, can you share the directory structure with us?

Comment: FYI -> "installing" JavaScript files => [script _"includes"_](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/script_tags.html)

Comment: @silverarrow Make sure you have imported jquery.js file is first js file. After that import barns.js

Comment: you don't *"install jQuery"* you just use it like any other JavaScript  file

Comment: Why did you tell us that you included `barns.js` _after_ jQuery if that's not what you really did?  You're lucky some people assumed your OP was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to include jQuery in your pages.  You can use a CDN like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or do it the way you use it by having a local copy and including that.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
```

Notice to use the second method, you must make sure the path to the script is correct.  So the above code says `jquery.js` is in the same directory as the page being viewed.  Next you must make sure the custom script you named `barns.js` is in the same directory also and the declaration comes after the declaration for jQuery.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="barns.js"></script>
```

Lastly some tips to keep in mind:

1. Use the developer tools of your browser to view the console to see any errors.  If you don't know what this is, Google it.
2. Use `console.log` to print things to the console in your developer tools to make sure certain parts of your code are being run.  This is an EXTREMELY helpful debugging technique.  For example, you can put `console.log('in script');` at the top of your custom JS script to make sure that the script is being brought in correctly.  This could help eliminate errors due to the path to the script being wrong.
3. Use the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).  It's great!
4. Experiment and have fun!

Comment: Not sure how this helps, since that's the way he's already doing it.

Comment: @searsaw they were the wrong way around... xP thanks so much, it's working fine now.

Comment: @Sparky looks like that wasn't how he was doing it...

Comment: Yes, I see.  I can only go by what he posted in his original question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add jQuery (as it's also a good option) is to use a cdn, like cdnjs.com:

Add this line before the closing boy tag (`</body>`):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When using a CDN, the jQuery JavaScript file doesn't need to be downloaded locally, because it is hosted on a cdn server. Thus it eliminates the need for the correct path to your local js file - which is probalby why you got the 'Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined' error.

More info about CDNs:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with the path in his script includes, then this answer makes no difference.

Comment: @Sparky, But most likely there is, in addition he might want to know about CDNs and how they help latency.

Answer (score 0):

A fast simple working example which uses jQuery to hide a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Red table should not be visible</h1>
    <table style="background: red;">
      <tr><td>If you see this, jQuery is not working</td></tr>
    </table>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery( function( $ ){
        $( 'table' ).hide();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your code is probably not working because scripts are not loaded (incorrect `src` attribute)